# I can't find a download for the Windows Driver Kit 8.1

Tags: visual-studio-2013, wdk, wdm

I am unable to find a download for the Windows Driver Kit 8.1 and I need it to do driver builds from VS 2013.  Or I need to upgrade my driver project to VS 2017.  Any recommendations?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/other-wdk-downloads

Comment: Thanks @Luke, but here's what I see for WDK 8.1:  Windows 8.1 Update WDK 8.1 Update (English only) - temporarily unavailable
WDK 8.1 Update Test Pack (English only) - temporarily unavailable
WDK 8.1 Samples

Comment: Strange. I'm almost positive those links were active when I posted it.

Comment: Hi Luke, I don't see them and haven't for some time.  Any ideas whom I would contact to help with that?

Comment: I see links to the 8.0 WDK but not 8.1.  Here's what I see:

Windows 8.1 Update WDK 8.1 Update (English only) - temporarily unavailable
WDK 8.1 Update Test Pack (English only) - temporarily unavailable
WDK 8.1 Samples

It looks like there's only support for updates not initial installs.

Comment: I would just upgrade to VS2017 and use the Win10 DDK. It can build for Windows 7 and above.

Comment: Two months later and the link is still "temporarily unavailable". I think it's likely it's gone for good.

Answer (score 3):

WDK 8.1 https://download.microsoft.com/download/8/6/9/86925F0F-D57A-4BA4-8278-861B6876D78E/wdk/wdksetup.exe

WDK 8.1 Update (via archive.org) http://web.archive.org/web/20200314015621if_/https://download.microsoft.com/download/0/8/C/08C7497F-8551-4054-97DE-60C0E510D97A/wdk/wdksetup.exe

The [reason](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windows-driver-docs/issues/2461#issuecomment-714663814) of removal: We removed the Windows 8.1 WDK downloads, because they do not meet our current requirements for downloadable files. They were signed by SHA-1 certificates, and we require SHA-2 certificates. As soon as we can rebuild and test these versions of the WDK, we will replace them.